# Cannot read property '@google-cloud/storage' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, module, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to build my project to deploy it to Heroku, but I am facing this problem:

`npm ERR! Cannot read property '@google-cloud/storage' of undefined`

Everytime I push to Heroku, it reinstall all the packages and build a new image. Locally, if I run:
`node -e "console.log(require.resolve('@google-cloud/storage'))"`

it works fine (the output is: `.../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js`)

Does anyone have an idea?

The project is a backend project with NodeJS and Express
node: v20.4.0
npm: 9.7.2
express: ^4.17.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example